# Android Studio crashes just a few minutes after opening

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio latest edition on Windows 10 and just a few minutes after opening and finishing opening a project it crashes. I have looked for a solution on the internet but I have not been able to find a solution. Every time it crashes I get text error report, my knowledge about Android Studio is very basic and I don't know how to interpret all this information, could someone be so kind to help me sort this out? Since the whole error file is very large I am posting here the header of the report I get, though the whole report is in Google Drive at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o670OcaW4AuOB8Dc_DgddaMsMH5iHHh3/view?usp=sharing

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x00007ff9797939af, pid=6752, tid=2448
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.10) (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.10+0-b96-7249189, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops,    g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libandroid_runtime.dll+0xb39af]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```