# Android studio closes automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, uninstallation

I have a problem with android studio, the problem is that the program closes automatically after it has been opened and the initial loading is finished (so after about a minute).

Unfortunately I am not given any errors, the program simply disappears, as if I had terminated the process.

I tried to search online but couldn't find any solution. I tried to uninstall the program, but from the control panel I was told that it could not be uninstalled and it disappeared from the list of programs, so I tried to reinstall it, but instead of being overwritten android studio is installed as a new program (in the folder "programfiles/Android Studio 1" etc)

PS Now I have 2 android studio that can't be uninstalled :(

Can you help me?

OS: Win10

[shorturl.at/dlLV3](http://shorturl.at/dlLV3) <- Logs (idea.log)

[shorturl.at/lCES0](http://shorturl.at/lCES0) <- Java error log

Comment: I'm afraid no one will be able to help without more information. Are there any logs available at any of the locations mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784877/how-to-find-the-logs-on-android-studio ? (this is for solving why it crashed in the first place, the uninstall may need a separate issue.

Comment: @SamBob shorturl.at/dlLV3 idea.log here

Comment: Sadly there's no obvious reason that Android Studio closes in those logs... this will need the attention of someone who knows the workings of android studio better than me...

Comment: @SamBob I found this other log: shorturl.at/lCES0

Comment: Ahah! It seems other users have had this same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258663/android-studio-crashes-just-a-few-minutes-after-opening and   https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android-studio-crahes-upon-opening.4336743/ Unfortunately there are no clear solutions for those questions yet either.

Comment: It doesn't work with me, I also reinstalled the operating system, switching from windows 10 to windows 11. I have still the same problem :/